# What is wrong with this input code?? and browser launcher in python

Tags: python, browser

this is the code    ...................................................when it runs it will only run the redditNeed == 1 and it opens 5 windows. And then when i hit any other the others besides main page it gives me webbrowser is not defined

```
    redditNeed = input("which subreddit do you want to reach; front page{1}, athesism{2}, bitcoin{3}, politics{4}, worldnews{5}")

    if redditNeed == 1:
        import webbrowser
        url="http://reddit.com"
        webbrowser.open(url)

    if redditNeed == 2:
        import webbrowser
        url="http://reddit.com/r/atheism"
        webbrowser.open(url)

    if redditNeed == 3:
        import webbrowser
        url="http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin"
        webbrowser.open(url)

    if redditNeed == 4:
        import webbrowser
        url="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics"
        webbrowser.open(url)

    if redditNeed == 5:
        import webbrowser
        url="http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews"
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: Please review the formatting, and explain why you think there is something wrong with the code. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You should use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input);
2. You should only `import webbrowser` once, at the top of the script;
3. Rather than branching `elif`s, use a dictionary to hold the options; and
4. You can use [`webbrowser.open`'s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) `new` argument to try to open a new tab.

Putting that together:

```
import webbrowser

reddits = {1: {"name": "Front Page", "url": "http://reddit.com"}, ...}

print("Which Reddit do you want?")
for r in sorted(reddits):
    print("{0}. {1[name]}".format(r, reddits[r])
reddit_need = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

webbrowser.open(reddits[reddit_need]["url"], 2)
```

Comment: i am running py 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect. Move the if statements back to the same indent as redditNeed == stuff

Comment: sorry missed that didnt copy right still not wroking