# What is wrong with this input code? and browser launcher in python

Tags: python

this is the code ...................................................when it runs it will only run the redditNeed == 1 and it opens 5 windows. And then when i hit any other the others besides main page it gives me webbrowser is not defined

```
redditNeed = input("which subreddit do you want to reach; front page{1}, athesism{2}, bitcoin{3}, politics{4}, worldnews{5}")

if redditNeed == 1:
    import webbrowser
    url="http://reddit.com"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == 2:
    import webbrowser
    url="http://reddit.com/r/atheism"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == 3:
    import webbrowser
    url="http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == 4:
    import webbrowser
    url="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == 5:
    import webbrowser
    url="http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews"
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: First: never `import` something inline! Import the things in the head. Next you can put the `webbrowser.open(url)` at the bottof of the ifthenelse methods. This will at least make it harder to make mistakes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this input code?? and browser launcher in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417972/what-is-wrong-with-this-input-code-and-browser-launcher-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things worth pointing out

1) You only need to import webbrowser once at the beginning

2) Use elif statements instead of if statements for each condition

3) You are comparing strings to ints, which will never be true, so you can either cast redditneed as an int like so int(redditneed) or compare it to a string such as "2", rather than 2.

4) If you're going to always open a webpage, just open it at the end of the ifs rather than doing it inside each individual if statement

5) I see from your comment that you're running python 2.7, that means you shouldn't use input, you should use raw_input

6) You asked for help without providing us with more detail, such as your python version or your error codes, that means it's harder for us to help you

7) Worst of all, you asked the exact same question an hour after you previously asked it here without trying anything new: [What is wrong with this input code?? and browser launcher in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417972/what-is-wrong-with-this-input-code-and-browser-launcher-in-python/22418763#22418763)

Here's an example of some equivalent code

```
import webbrowser

redditNeed = raw_input("which subreddit do you want to reach; front page{1}, atheism{2}, bitcoin{3}, politics{4}, worldnews{5}")
redditNeed = int(redditNeed)

if   redditNeed == 1: url="http://reddit.com"
elif redditNeed == 2: url="http://reddit.com/r/atheism"
elif redditNeed == 3: url="http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin"
elif redditNeed == 4: url="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics"
else:                 url="http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews"

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: sorry about that didn't mean to cause a problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string (value returned from input) with a integer. Try changing to:

```
import webbrowser

# For python2.7, use raw_input(...)
redditNeed = input("which subreddit do you want to reach; front page{1}, athesism{2}, bitcoin{3}, politics{4}, worldnews{5}")

if redditNeed == "1":
    url="http://reddit.com"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == "2":
    url="http://reddit.com/r/atheism"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == "3":
    url="http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == "4":
    url="http://www.reddit.com/r/politics"
    webbrowser.open(url)

if redditNeed == "5":
    url="http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews"
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Or as @GWW suggests, converting the input to integer using `int(...)`

Moreover, it is a good practise not to make imports in the middle of our code, just make then at the beggining of the file.

Comment: Or convert the input to an integer ;)

Comment: but if OP is on python2... `input` will most likely return an `int` since most people will type `1` and not `"1"`...